# Snowflake: Error loading a LOCAL file that has some ARRAY fields

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting an Error when loading a LOCAL file that has some ARRAY fields.
I do not get this for source files where all fields are STRINGS.

CREATED TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTDB"."LAYER2"."CREW" ("TCONST" STRING, "DIRECTORS" ARRAY, "WRITERS" ARRAY);
```

DATA FILE:

```
tconst  directors   writers
tt0000001   nm0005690   \N
tt0000002   nm0721526   \N
tt0000003   nm0721526   \N
tt0000004   nm0721526   \N
tt0000005   nm0005690   \N
tt0000006   nm0617588   nm0617588
tt0000007   nm0374658,nm0005690 \N
tt0000008   nm0719756   nm0331003,nm0759866,nm0173952,nm0719756,nm0816458
```

SQL

```
PUT file://<file_path>/title.crew_1.tsv @TEST_2/ui1770650179898

COPY INTO "TESTDB"."LAYER2"."TEST_2" FROM @/ui1770650179898 
FILE_FORMAT = '"TESTDB"."LAYER1"."TSV"' ON_ERROR = 
'ABORT_STATEMENT' PURGE = TRUE;
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Unable to copy files into table. Error parsing JSON: nm0005690 File
> '@TEST_2/ui1770650179898/sample.samplefile.tsv', line 2, character 11
> Row 1, column "TEST_2"["DIRECTORS":2]  If you would like to continue
> loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as
> 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option.  For more
> information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a
> SQL client.

I feel it is an easy answer -- troubleshooted various methods with no success and could not find anything on the web to point me in the right direction.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert strings to arrays. I assume that the delimiter is the tab character:

```
create file format csvtab type=csv field_delimiter = '\t' skip_header=1;

COPY INTO "CREW" FROM 
(select $1, SPLIT($2,','), SPLIT($3,',') from @mystage)
FILE_FORMAT = csvtab ON_ERROR = 'ABORT_STATEMENT' ;

select * from "CREW";

+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  TCONST   |         DIRECTORS         |                            WRITERS                            |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| tt0000001 | ["nm0005690"]             |                                                               |
| tt0000002 | ["nm0721526"]             |                                                               |
| tt0000003 | ["nm0721526"]             |                                                               |
| tt0000004 | ["nm0721526"]             |                                                               |
| tt0000005 | ["nm0005690"]             |                                                               |
| tt0000006 | ["nm0617588"]             | ["nm0617588"]                                                 |
| tt0000007 | ["nm0374658","nm0005690"] |                                                               |
| tt0000008 | ["nm0719756"]             | ["nm0331003","nm0759866","nm0173952","nm0719756","nm0816458"] |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Gokhan - Thank you for your response.  I will be testing tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  One quick question -- besides SnowSQL -- do you know of any other way to use the worksheet to copy files to the STAGE.  I do not think you can use the put command.

Comment: Never mind looks like I will be downloading SnowSQL -- to upload.